# Prove $f_{1} + f_{3} + f_{5} +...+f_{2n-1} = f_{2n}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Prove  $f_{1} + f_{3} + f_{5} +...+f_{2n-1} = f_{2n}$ when $f_{n}$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Before I try to prove this, I am trying to understand this in English. What is happening in this equation? How can $2n-1 = 2n$? What is the English interpretation of this?

Comment: By $f_1+f_3+f_5+\dots+f_{2n-1}=f_{2n}$ They are saying $f_1+f_3=f_4$ and $f_1+f_3+f_5=f_6$ as well as $f_1+f_3+f_5+f_7=f_8$ etc... in general $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f_{2k-1}=f_{2n}$.  If it happens to be true, it will depend on what specifically the sequence $f_n$ is and the properties thereof.

Comment: @JMoravitz For the inductive proof here is an example: it is true for n=1 
F1 = F2 
1 = 1 

suppose it is true for n 
F1 + F3 + F5 + ... + F2n-1 = F2n 

let's prove it for (n + 1) 
F1 + F3 + F5 + ... + F2n-1 + F2n+1 = F2n+2 
(F1 + F3 + F5 + ... + F2n-1) + F2n+1 = F2n+2 
F2n + F2n+1 = F2n+2

How does he deduce that f1 = f2? 
How does F2n-1 + F2n+1 = F2n+2?

Comment: You tell me.  What is $f_1$?  What is $f_2$?  (*what is $f$ in the first place*)  Do those happen to be equal?

Comment: @JMoravitz I am interpreting f1 and f2 as terms not numbers...terms in the sequence?

Comment: If they happen to be representative of the Fibonacci numbers, by **definition** $f_0=0, f_1=1, f_2=1$ and in general $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ for all other values of $n\geq 2$.  If it was a different sequence, then that might not necessarily be the case and the statement could be false.

Comment: @JMoravitz ok let me understand this: fn is the nth term that we have not yet wrote down or who is next in the sequence, fn-1 is the previous number in the sequence and fn-2 is what? When I plug 1 into the formula n-1+n-2 I get 1-1 + 1-2 = -1 and I know this is not what it is saying. Pleas forgive me if it is obvious.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence starts: 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,...  (*where $0$ is the "zero'th" number in the sequence*) and it follows the property that every number in the sequence is the sum of the previous two numbers.  (*e.g. $34=13+21$.  Also $21=8+13$ and $13=5+8$ etc..., so what number is next after $34$?*).  By $f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}=f_n$ we are saying exactly that property I mention, that if you add two consecutive numbers, you get the number that follows that.  We are not saying that $n-1+n-2=n$ we are saying *the $(n-1)$'st number plus the $(n-2)$'nd number is the $n$'th number*.

Comment: @JMoravitz   Ok, got it! you are pure genius!